# PHP IMAP retrieve UNSEEN emails from server

Tags: php, imap

I am working on a Cron job script that collects Unseen emails from Google imap server to my database. But sometimes, some emails are not read, so they don't get saved into the database.
Here is the code:

```
$connection = imap_open ($imapaddressandbox, $imapuser, $imappassword)
        or die("Can't connect to '" . $imapaddress .
        "' as user '" . $imapuser .
        "' with password '" . $imappassword .
        "': " . imap_last_error());

$m_search=imap_search ($connection, 'UNSEEN');
if($m_search === false){
email_log("No New Messages ");
}
```

It seams like for some reason some emails get skipped although they are unread.

Can anyone have an idea why?

Just a note, email is like me@mydomain.com, but using google email.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't echo the password in your `die`...

Comment: I don't have much time to look it all or test it all but your "===" might be overkill. It implies that the $m_search result must be a boolean result AND false. What do you do on true?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 imap_open($incoming_server,$username, $password,FT_PEEK);
```

Comment: Please add an explaination why you think that this solves the problem. Otherwise, it lacks context and is likely to be removed due to “low quality”.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (!$m_search) {
    // No new mails found
}
```